# Does JPEG 2000 (JP2) support transparency when created?

Tags: transparency-opacity, jpeg-2000

I haven't been able to find any resources that can provide if in JPEG 2000 (JP2) transparency can be "built-in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG2000 does support transparency.  See the GDAL file formats documentation [here](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_jp2openjpeg.html).  Also see the relevant [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000#Side_channel_spatial_information) and not the 'side channel spatial information' section.